# Timer publisher init timer after button click

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

In all tutorials and in official documentation I only see initialization of timer straight up when the view loads.

```
@State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

and later on

```
.onReceive(timer) {....}
```

but how should I init timer only on button click and assign it to the unassigned / not connected timer.

Later on I will need to cancel and reconnect, but that is not the issue here. Issue here is connecting only after button click.

I tried to init it like this

```
@State private var timer: Cancellable?
```

....

```
timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).connect()
```

But I can not call onReceive on timer inited like this, because first:

```
Protocol 'Cancellable' as a type cannot conform to 'Publisher'
```

and second

```
Argument type 'Cancellable?' does not conform to expected type 'Cancellable'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the timer in a child view and control its visibility with a bool. When the `TimerView` is removed the state is destroyed and the timer stops.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var started = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(started ? "Stop" : "Start") {
                started.toggle()
            }
            if started {
                TimerView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TimerView: View {

    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    ...
```

Comment: Yes I went with similar approach. in init I autoconnected timer but bool that allows action to happen when timer fires was false so no action was done. Immediately then I canceled timer, and waited for proper timer start where bool will be true.

Comment: you don't need another bool in TimerView

Answer (score 2):

Here is demo of possible approach - timer publisher is created with button (same autoconnected), but subscriber should be registered conditionally, because timer in such case is an optional.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var timer: Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher>? // << here !!

    @State private var value = 10 // just demo

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            if timer != nil {
                timer = nil     // << reset !!
                value = 10
            } else {
                timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()    // << create !!
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Toggle")
        }
        if timer != nil {              // << verify !!
            Text("Counter: \(value)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .onReceive(timer!) { _ in     // << observe !!
                    value = value == 0 ? 10 : value - 1
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And is there a way to check if the timer is running? Let's say that I will not init timer as optional. If I cancel it immidiately in the init can I check if the timer is cancelled or no?

Comment: It differs from scenario in question. In originally described use-case no, but in general there might be other solution. Currently setting timer=nil is equivalent of cancel (actually it does cancel subscription).